# How to apply Where clause to secondary table

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I have an Entity created with a main table and 2 associated tables. I joined the primary-secondary tables using the hibernate annotations.
Here is the code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Table1")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate=true)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Tables ( {
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "Table2", optional = false ),
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "Table3", optional = false )
})
//@org.hibernate.annotations.Table(appliesTo = "Table2", optional = false )
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="t1_column1")
@SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name = "Table2", pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "t2_col1", referencedColumnName = "t1_col1")}  ),
    @SecondaryTable(name = "Table3", pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "t3_col1", referencedColumnName = "t1_col1")})
})
```

This works fine. I want to specify a Where annotation that will apply to the secondary table 'Table2'. By default the hibernate annotation "@Where" gets applied to only the target table which here is 'Table1'. As a result, I get an SQL error that the column included in the where clause is not found  in 'Table1'.

Is there any special directive that I need to add to the @Where to make hibernate add the SQL where clause on the secondary table Table2?

Comment: This looks like a known issue - I haven't been able to find a fix https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4246

Answer (score 0):

I guess @Where and @WhereJoinTable is what your want